# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: boolean org.glassfish.jersey.internal.config.SystemPropertiesConfigurationModel.hasProperty(java.lang.String)

Tags: maven, jersey, jax-rs

```
<dependency>
<groupId>jakarta.platform</groupId>
<artifactId>jakarta.jakartaee-api</artifactId>
<version>9.1.0</version>
<scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

I've included the Jakarta dependency in my project, specifying version 9.1.0 and marked it as 'provided,' yet I'm encountering the same error.

Comment: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'boolean org.glassfish.jersey.internal.config.SystemPropertiesConfigurationModel.hasProperty(java.lang.String)'

Answer (score 0):

Your Maven dependency is incorrect.

`org.glassfish.jersey.internal.config.SystemPropertiesConfigurationModel` is not part of `akarta.jakartaee-api`.

Add this dependency instead (if you don't use anything else from jakarta):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
    <version>2.33</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: This won't work jakartaee 9 api.

Comment: We don't even know, if jakartaee 9 api is needed at all.